# click on select dropdown to call ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, onclick, jquery-select2

i've a problem calling ajax when I click the dropdown with select2.
this is my html code:

```js
//call ajax when select button do click
function showAjax() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "hanca/hanca_crud.php",
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        type: "get_hanca"
      }, //get_kode_hanca dan nama model serta jumlahnya
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        var teks = "";
        $.each(data, function(index, val) { //looping table detail bahan
          var id_hanca = val.id_hanca;
          var nama_model = val.nm_model;
          var sisa = val.jumlah_hanca;

          teks += "<option value='" + id_hanca + "'>" + nama_model + " - " + id_hanca + " - [sisa " + sisa + " Pcs]" + "</option>";
        });
        $(".id_hanca").append(teks);
      }
    });

  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select onchange="anotherAjax(this)" onclick="showAjax" name="id_hanca[]" class="form-control id_hanca" required="">
  <option value="">- SELECT</option>
</select>
```

is this possible?

Comment: You need parentheses after the function name: `onclick="showAjax()"`

Comment: oh, sorry. i forgot re-paste that. i have been do that. but, the ajax cannot call when i click the `select option`. would you give me some code ?

Comment: Does it work if you don't use the Select2 plugin?

Comment: What happens when you try? Any errors in the console? Checked the browsers network tab to see if a request gets triggered? Something that's good to know is that `onClick` will be triggered not only when you click on the select, but also when you click on an option, so your ajax would be called every single time someone opens/closes/selects an option (and therefore keep adding the same rows over and over).

Comment: did you look at the ajax built into the Select2?  If not, you need to destroy and reinitialize the selects once the data is appended to the select box.